# Django schedule a "one time" task based on datetime model attribute

Tags: python, django, scheduled-tasks, celery

What the best solution in Django to solve this kind of problem:

I need to set a schedule time, based on an object attribute value, to run a "one time" task, when schedule time is reached.

For each attribute updates, the schedule time has to be also updated.

**Example (pseudo code)**

```
class Runner(models.Model):
    execute_time = models.DateTimeField()

post_save( update_scheduler, sender=Runner)


def update_scheduler(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        # set schedule time = instance.execute_time
        create_or_update_schedule(instance.datetime)
```

Is it possibile to do something like this using Celery? update schedule time on object update?

Comment: You can use the [eta](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/calling.html#eta-and-countdown) attribute to schedule a single task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Banana suggested, I solved this issue using eta.
Here a simple sample code:

```
task.apply_async([ev_objects], eta=my_eta, task_id=my_task_id)
```

Also "[revoke](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/workers.html#revoke-revoking-tasks)" can come in handy to terminate a task that hasn't start yet. It's a remote control command so it wouldn't work with django database solution but only with Redis or RabbitMQ.

I'm still [searching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25046200/celery-revoke-task-before-execute-using-django-database) for a solution to revoke a task using Django database.